# Searching google videos of a particular size

Tags: google-search, video

Is it possible to search videos on http://google.com with different parameters like size in MB, GB or resolution or file type etc. Just like we have for Images.

Is it possible to apply some query parameters to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what you need.

You can access **advanced search** on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com) by clicking the **Filter** link below your search result videos. There, you can filter results by:

- Type of results, such as Videos, Channels, or Playlists
- Upload date
- Subject category
- Video length
- Video quality
- Features, such as Closed captions, Partner videos, or Rentals

You can also sort your results by:

- Relevance
- Upload date
- View count
- Rating

You can close the options box by clicking **Filter** again after making your selections.

You might also be looking for [Google Videos](https://video.google.com/) (Not YouTube). You can perform [advanced searches for Google Videos](https://www.google.com/advanced_video_search).